# Getting unexpected lifetime issue when passing newly constructed array to function

Tags: rust, solana

I've been working on a program intended to run on the Solana runtime. I've recently run into a problem where the second item in the array being passed into 'test2' gets some sort of lifetime error. This error goes away when explicit lifetime annotations are added to test1 but I can't figure out why it shows up in the first place.

```
pub fn test1(
    test_account_1: &AccountInfo,
    test_account_2: &AccountInfo,
    mint_account: &AccountInfo,
) -> ProgramResult {
    test2(&[test_account_1.clone(), test_account_2.clone()]);
    return Ok(());
}

pub fn test2(arr: &[AccountInfo]) {
    for a in arr.iter() {
        println!("{}", a.key)
    }
}
```

The error:

> lifetime mismatch

> ...but data from `test_account_1` flows into `test_account_2`
> here rustc (E0623)

> lib.rs(207, 22): these two types are declared with
> different lifetimes...

> lib.rs(208, 22):

> lib.rs(211, 37): ...but data
> from `test_account_1` flows into `test_account_2` here

Definition of AccountInfo:

```
/// Account information
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct AccountInfo<'a> {
    /// Public key of the account
    pub key: &'a Pubkey,
    /// Was the transaction signed by this account's public key?
    pub is_signer: bool,
    /// Is the account writable?
    pub is_writable: bool,
    /// The lamports in the account.  Modifiable by programs.
    pub lamports: Rc<RefCell<&'a mut u64>>,
    /// The data held in this account.  Modifiable by programs.
    pub data: Rc<RefCell<&'a mut [u8]>>,
    /// Program that owns this account
    pub owner: &'a Pubkey,
    /// This account's data contains a loaded program (and is now read-only)
    pub executable: bool,
    /// The epoch at which this account will next owe rent
    pub rent_epoch: Epoch,
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that reproduces the error (e.g. on the [online playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)).

Comment: Unless you have a particular need, I'd highly recommend you switch your `&'a Pubkey` fields to just `Pubkey` and own the data, and similarly get rid of the lifetime annotations on the RefCells. (Ideally, I'd get rid of these RefCells, as well. They're very suspicious. Making a `RefCell` public is very strange IMO. It's going to very hard to avoid crashing the program. If you're using references to avoid copies, you might look at `std::borrow::Cow` instead. If you're having to mark a lot of lifetimes on simple, non-generic code, you probably are on the wrong path IMO.

Comment: The AccountInfo struct was taken from the Solana library (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/c4a9c8b5e993ce5e854244d28d5fd3ccc7c5b233/sdk/program/src/account_info.rs#L15) , I was just trying to make a minimally reproducible example. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your array to hold a reference to those `AccountsInfo`, they need to live for at least the same lifetime. Since they have internal bounds, those need to match too:

```rust
pub fn test1<'a>(
    test_account_1: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    test_account_2: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    mint_account: &AccountInfo,
) -> Result<(), ()> {
    test2(&[test_account_1.clone(), test_account_2.clone()]);
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4cbc149c91489628047e01046d387763)

Also, depending on your actual needs, you may not need the clone at all:

```rust
pub fn test1<'a>(
    test_account_1: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    test_account_2: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    mint_account: &AccountInfo,
) -> Result<(), ()> {
    test2(&[test_account_1, test_account_2]);
    Ok(())
}

pub fn test2(arr: &[&AccountInfo]) {
    for a in arr.iter() {
        println!("{}", a.key)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7971584f66aaf39e886d41cafd4e2fd7)

Comment: I guess a follow up question to that is why I don't have to declare lifetimes if I changed AccountInfo to a struct with lifetimes defined for i32 references like so?: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67754e3c35df3da3e394a16c91e95692

Comment: `i32` implements `Copy`. It can make trivial bitwise copies, so the calls to `clone` are certain to create independent objects. In that case, the lifetimes don't need to match each other, and [Lifetime Elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) kicks in so you don't need to actually write them.

Comment: Would you agree that the message about data from test_account_2 flowing into test_account_1 just because they are in an array is kinda wrong?